# Excel 2016 VBA code Listbox1 not updating in real time. Data format different from sheet. Mouse scroll not working

Tags: excel, vba, userform, real-time-updates

I posted a question few days ago and it was difficult for me to explain that how I wanted the form to perform search. It got no answer; perhaps my lack of understanding of terms is to blame, although a few folks from here tried to help with it. I have since deleted the question and I'm trying to think of another way to achieve what I want userform to do.

I'm now using the ListBox1 to display the entire content of the sheet. I've come across few issues while doing this.

**What to achieve:**

ListBox1 should display entire content of a sheet based upon the selection from a ComboBox which is named as SelectMonth on UserForm2.

**What's working:**

I've managed to get the ListBox1 working and it's displaying the content of active/open sheet in the background.

**What's not working/properly:**

ListBox1 is not updating in realtime. Once an entry is made the UserForm2 needs to be closed and restart again in order for ListBox1 to be updated and show the last made entry.

The date format on the sheet is DD/MM/YYYY date format displayed in ListBox1 is MM/DD/YYYY so ListBox1 is not showing the date format in the correct way.

All Sheets have 7 columns. I've set the ListBox1 appropriately to show column heads too. But, but ListBox1 showing the Column(s) headings from the sheet on the outside of ListBox1 ColumnHeads.

Mouse scroll doesn't work in ListBox1

**The code which I'm using for ListBox1:**

The following code is entered in Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

```
  ListBox1.List = wsActive.Range("G8", wsActive.Range("A8").End(xlDown)).Value
```

It is worth mentioning that Row 8 on sheet is where the header(s) are hence I included G8 to A8 to call the values? (In my mind it's how it works?) from Row 9 actual data starts and so on.

**Code from Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()**

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim wsActive As Worksheet
Dim i As Long, LastRow As Long
Set wsActive = ActiveSheet
LastRow = wsActive.Cells(wsActive.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
Me.SelectMonth.AddItem ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name
Next
```

I think above code sets the active sheet based on the selection from Combobox named SelectMonth. Ideally The same selection can be used to display ListBox1 but in real time rather then restarting the form again to see the last entry made in the sheet.

So if Selectmonth combobox is changed from January 2019 to March 2019 ListBox1 should display the entire sheet from March 2019 and show in update it real time if any entries are made while the userform was open and not having to restart the userform again.

Comment: If this is difficult to achieve then perhaps somebody can suggest an alternate way of performing search from a userform. I'm open to suggestions. I do need listbox to show the results and be able to edit them rather then having a duplicate entry. I've spent all day today to read up similar posts on here but most are for advanced users hence for me they are all bit difficult to understand. I appreciate your help if anybody can step forward with a suggestion. Thanks in advance. Cheers.

Comment: I have made a userform and have it partly working. I can not make the search work or the combobox in the search work. Listbox doesn't work. I think it's because of my workbook having 13 sheets and the example I'm trying to follow only have one sheet. Other sheet reference and parameters are different than mine. If I post the link here of the file and the original code, can anybody have a look at it and make any sense of it to work with my combobox? Any help is appreciated. Cheers.